# How to read a file inside the Dropbox folder using Python Dropbox API v2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to use Python 3.4 to upload files in dropbox. I can successfully upload files to dropbox. But I need to know how files inside a Dropbox folder can be read. For ex: if there are text and csv files inside a dropbox folder, then I need to read the contents of those file using Python Dropbox API v2?

Answer (score 2):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/issues/89 ]

You can use the `files_download` methods to download files from Dropbox:

https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download

The examples use the Python SDK `file_download` methods here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py#L158
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/back-up-and-restore/backup-and-restore-example.py#L55

Comment: Is there no way to read files from dropbox folder itself rather than downloading to local path and then read?

Comment: The `files_download` method gives you a response object you can read the file data from. You don't need to save it to a local file though. E.g.: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/master/example/updown.py#L158